# php based paid membership solution

Tags: membership

I need a very light weight solution for paid membership. There will be 3 levels of membership. One free and the rest are paid.
I don't need all the bells and whistles of big frameworks.
All I need is registration and payment handling such as monthly payments and membership upgrades.
Paypal will be my last option for the payments so other payments options are welcome too.

Comment: Paypal is your last? Who else is in the running? Authorize.net is another possible option. It's ill-advised to handle the payment processing yourself when there are well-tested systems that do it already and are [PCI compliant](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Braintree](http://www.braintreepayments.com/) provides braindead simple handling of subscriptions and memberships, and deals with all the payments, recurring charges, and handling.  It's pretty simple to get set up, and has a very [lightweight API](http://www.braintreepayments.com/gateway) for most languages to integrate it with your app, including PHP.

We use it for our company, and it's been reliable, with excellent support.

Comment: Yeah I'd say this already looks better than authorize

Comment: I am tired of  paypal and authorize. Braintree seems really good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use of the term "light weight" may be subjective here. You can implement an authorize.net standard subscription system with very little code. They provide an API that is not difficult to work with if, even for a novice. How you choose to use the API will determine how you handle "upgrades"

This is a link but it is not the documentation: http://www.authorize.net/solutions/merchantsolutions/merchantservices/automatedrecurringbilling/

It has been some time since I used the ARB package so I'm sure they've solved the problems with membership cancellation from some 6 years ago. You'd probably need to speak with them to get some docs on it.

Just one option.